# Button doesn't get hovered and alignment is not centered

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I got a small navigation bar and I want the buttons to be centered in this container. I also want a hover effect, when entering them with the mouse.

Somehow the alignment and hover effect is not working, I use flex instead of floating. So I want the container of the buttons to be centered and the buttons being hovered with a color effect.

Thanks!

Here's a fiddle

```css
#navBar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

#btnBar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f85d4d;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navBtn:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
    <div id="navBar">
      <div id="btnBar">
        <button class="btn" class="navBtn">New Folder</button>
        <button class="btn" class="navBtn">New File</button>
        <button class="btn" class="navBtn">Delete</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        navContent
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: class="btn" class="navBtn" This is wrong. Do somthing like class="btn navBtn"

Comment: oh cool, hovering works fine now, didn't know that :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to use all your classes inside one class attribute `class="btn navBtn"`

And to center a flex items you need to use `justify-content:center;` on flex container

See code snippet:

```css
#navBar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

#btnBar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f85d4d;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navBtn:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navBar">
  <div id="btnBar">
    <button class="btn navBtn">New Folder</button>
    <button class="btn navBtn">New File</button>
    <button class="btn navBtn">Delete</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    navContent
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use  `justify-content: center;` to center items inside the flex container.and remeber use only single class attribute for element If you want to use multiple class use `class="btn navBtn"`

```css
#navBar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

#btnBar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f85d4d;
  color: #ffffff;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navBtn:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  transition:all 0.5s linear;
}



.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navBar">
      <div id="btnBar">
        <button class="btn navBtn">New Folder</button>
        <button class="btn navBtn" >New File</button>
        <button class="btn navBtn" >Delete</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        navContent
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass multiple classes then use only single attribute `class="YourClassName"` and pass your class name.

**`class="btn" class="navBtn" This is wrong. Do somthing like class="btn navBtn"`**

```css
#navBar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

#btnBar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f85d4d;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navBtn:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
    <div id="navBar">
      <div id="btnBar">
        <button class="btn navBtn">New Folder</button>
        <button class="btn navBtn">New File</button>
        <button class="btn navBtn">Delete</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        navContent
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I forgot to add alignment issue. Use `justify-content: center;`.

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one "class" attribute for a single element like this.

**Delete**

Try this:

```css
#navBar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

#btnBar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f85d4d;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navBtn:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
    <div id="navBar">
      <div id="btnBar">
        <button class="btn navBtn">New Folder</button>
        <button class="btn navBtn">New File</button>
        <button class="btn navBtn">Delete</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        navContent
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `.btn:hover`you should write changes you want to appear. Also, you can use `flexbox` display to justify your contents.

```css
#navBar {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#btnBar {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #f85d4d;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navBtn:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
    <div id="navBar">
      <div id="btnBar">
        <button class="btn" class="navBtn">New Folder</button>
        <button class="btn" class="navBtn">New File</button>
        <button class="btn" class="navBtn">Delete</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>navContent<p>
      </div>
    </div>
```